# The units parameter in a Keras RNN

Tags: keras, recurrent-neural-network

I am struggling to understand the Architecture implemented by the following Keras snippet:

```python
HIDDEN_DIM=256
VOCAB_SIZE=80
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=HIDDEN_DIM, input_shape=(None, VOCAB_SIZE), return_sequences=True))
for i in range(LAYER_NUM - 1):
    model.add(LSTM(units=HIDDEN_DIM, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(VOCAB_SIZE)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="rmsprop")
```

Specifically, I don't really understand the "units" parameter. does the unit parameter define the number of timesteps, or does it define the number of LSTMs for each timestep (i.e. the number of "channels")?

Answer (score 0):

Units parameter defines the number of hidden units in the LSTM. Number of timesteps will be defined by the number of words in the sentence.